# How to create a Docker in Docker Service on Docker Swarm (Swan Mode)

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, docker-in-docker

I would like to run (Docker-in-Docker) DIND inside a SWARM cluster(Swarm Mode).

As Swarm does not support the `--privileged` flag its not possible to start a DIND Container like you see in the tutorials. However `--privileged` can be "emulated"

What `--cap-add` flags should be used in oder to be able to run DIND in Swarm Mode?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm trying to do the same thing...

Comment: Yes, Kubernetes.

Comment: Heh. Was afraid of this being the long-term answer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @MoritzFriedrich did you find a solution? :D I just hope...

Comment: Well, in a way: I opted for mounting the Docker socket as a volume instead (`/var/run/docker.sock:ro`). This way, all you need is a Docker client and you're good to go, but be aware that you're talking to Docker on the Swarm host, not inside an isolated environment. That was good enough for my purposes.